# Detect the user that last changed a file in a Unix System

Tags: unix

Is there a way to detect the username of the last person that changed a file in a Unix environment?

Comment: If `sudo` was used to do it, a log entry should be in `/var/log`, `/var/log/auth.log` on my system.

Answer (score 4):

In retrospect, no, other than making assumptions based on user login times and who has permission to change the file and the timestamp of the changed file.

In advance, you can install [auditd](http://www.osnews.com/story/24033) and set it up to watch for changes to files.

Answer (score 3):

Install some logging software like [Auditd](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html).

Also, maybe you can look at your history.